# How to log in to Drupal 7 website with jmeter

Tags: 7, testing

I am trying to set up an load test using jmeter.  As part of the test I want to be able to log in as the site administrator and then go to admin page.

For some reason the test is not able to login as the adminstrator.  I followed the instructions in this [tutorial](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-jmeter-to-test-performance-of-drupal-with-authenticated-users/).  That tutorial was written for D6 so I did make some changes for D7 (e.g. changed the regex used to get the form_build_id). However it is still not working.  I would be very grateful for any suggestions on why this is occurring.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.7" jmeter="2.12 r1636949">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="API test" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Authenticated user" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
      <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
    <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1425852247000</longProp>
    <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1425852247000</longProp>
    <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
    <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">d6.dev</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">4</stringProp>
    </ConfigTestElement>
    <hashTree/>
    <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Home page" enabled="true">
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
    </HTTPSamplerProxy>
    <hashTree>
      <HTMLAssertion guiclass="HTMLAssertionGui" testclass="HTMLAssertion" testname="HTML Assertion" enabled="true">
        <longProp name="html_assertion_error_threshold">0</longProp>
        <longProp name="html_assertion_warning_threshold">0</longProp>
        <stringProp name="html_assertion_doctype">omit</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="html_assertion_errorsonly">true</boolProp>
        <longProp name="html_assertion_format">0</longProp>
        <stringProp name="html_assertion_filename"></stringProp>
      </HTMLAssertion>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
          <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
        </collectionProp>
        <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
        <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">1</intProp>
      </ResponseAssertion>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
    <OnceOnlyController guiclass="OnceOnlyControllerGui" testclass="OnceOnlyController" testname="Once Only Controller" enabled="true"/>
    <hashTree>
      <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
      </CookieManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="login page" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/user</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
      </HTTPSamplerProxy>
      <hashTree>
        <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="get form id" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">form_build_id</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">id=”(form-.{43})”</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">1.0</stringProp>
        </RegexExtractor>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Send login" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
            <elementProp name="name" elementType="HTTPArgument">
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">CCA_Web</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">name</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="pass" elementType="HTTPArgument">
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">XXXXXXXXXX</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">pass</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="form_build_id" elementType="HTTPArgument">
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">${form_build_id}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">form_build_id</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="form_id" elementType="HTTPArgument">
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">user_login</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">form_id</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="op" elementType="HTTPArgument">
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">Log in</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">op</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/user</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
      </HTTPSamplerProxy>
      <hashTree>
        <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response code 200" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
            <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">1</intProp>
        </ResponseAssertion>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Login details correct" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
            <stringProp name="-1477566849">unrecognized username or password</stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_data</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">6</intProp>
        </ResponseAssertion>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="admin page" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/admin</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
      </HTTPSamplerProxy>
      <hashTree>
        <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="! response code 403" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
            <stringProp name="51511">403</stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">6</intProp>
        </ResponseAssertion>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
    <ResultCollector guiclass="TableVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results in Table" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
      <objProp>
        <name>saveConfig</name>
        <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
          <time>true</time>
          <latency>true</latency>
          <timestamp>true</timestamp>
          <success>true</success>
          <label>true</label>
          <code>true</code>
          <message>true</message>
          <threadName>true</threadName>
          <dataType>true</dataType>
          <encoding>false</encoding>
          <assertions>true</assertions>
          <subresults>true</subresults>
          <responseData>false</responseData>
          <samplerData>false</samplerData>
          <xml>false</xml>
          <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
          <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
          <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
          <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
          <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
          <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
          <bytes>true</bytes>
          <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
        </value>
      </objProp>
      <stringProp name="filename">/home/bgunn/dev/load tests/CCA.jtl</stringProp>
    </ResultCollector>
    <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way to start is to use https://github.com/jacobSingh/Drupal-Performance-Testing-Suite

1. Download DrupalStress.jmx
2. Open up the jmx file
3. Enable either Drupal-6 or Drupal-7 config sections (not both).
4. Edit the config section and change the host to reflect your target machine